# Better IntelliSense Filter/Search List with Text and icons on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am just doing an IntelliSense  Filter/Search List which is in pure JavaScript. I want it better using jQuery with less code and efficient as I have less idea using jQuery library. Also onkeydown it's not working properly and the dropdown list is not closing onkeydown.

Please suggest me the changes and can I add tabs on it as shown in this picture below?

[image: IntelliSense search with tabs]

**[The Javasript:](https://jsfiddle.net/dazvxg01/)**

```js
function intelliSearch() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('intelliSearchField');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("intelliSearch");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        ul.style.display="block";
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > +1) {
            ul.style.display="none";
        }
    }
}

function intelliSearchDown() {
    var xdx;
    xdx = document.getElementById("intelliSearch");
    ul.style.display="none";
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="search-box hidden-xs">
  <form class="sidebar-search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="intelliSearch()" onBlur="intelliSearchDown()" id="intelliSearchField">
      <button class="submit"> <i class="clip-search-3"></i> </button>
      <ul class="" id="intelliSearch" style="display: none;">
        <li><i class="clip-user-2"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Test deal</a></li>
        <li><i class="clip-settings"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Testing deal</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><i class="clip-user-2"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Paul Testing</a></li>
        <li><i class="clip-user-plus"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Add More User</a></li>
        <li><i class="clip-users-2 "></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Invite Friends</a></li>
        <li><i class="clip-exit"></i> &nbsp;<a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dazvxg01/18/ and it should get you going:

```
$(function(){
    $('#intelliSearchField').keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
    if(value.length > 0){
      $('#intelliSearch').show();
      $('#intelliSearch').find('li').filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      });
    }else{
        $('#intelliSearch').hide();
    }

    $("#intelliSearch li").click(function(){
     $('#intelliSearchField').val($(this).text());
     $('#intelliSearch').hide();
    })


  });
});
```

Comment: After clicking the result its not scope to the text box. Any way

Comment: Working very nice